# Javascript code in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, multiline

How can I save in  a variable a javascript code, I did that but I did not succeed:

```
var reportD = '<html><head>';
reportD = reportD + '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>';
reportD = reportD + '<script type="text/javascript">';
reportD = reportD + 'google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});';
reportD = reportD + '</script>';
reportD = reportD + '<script type="text/javascript">';
reportD = reportD + 'function drawVisualization() {';
reportD = reportD + 'var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["x", "Cats", "Blanket 1", "Blanket 2"],["N",1,0.5,1]]);';
reportD = reportD + 'new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("visualization")).';
reportD = reportD + 'draw(data, {curveType: "function",width: 500, height: 400,vAxis: {maxValue: 10}});';
reportD = reportD + '}google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);';
reportD = reportD + "</script>";
reportD = reportD + '</head>';
reportD = reportD + '<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">';
reportD = reportD + '<div id="visualization" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>';
reportD = reportD + '</body></html>';
```

I want to do that, in order to inject these code in an iframe element

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: having this much javascript in a string should be a flag that you should step back and rethink the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string/comment/whatever inside a `script>` tag may not contain `</script>`. Escape the forward slash using `\` and it should work (i.e. `<\/script>`)

Answer (score 0):

Write your html(notepad/your ide), copy it
Goto

> http://accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/html-javascript-convertor/

paste in your html, convert to JS variable.